# Arguments passed to nested function with yield keyword

Tags: python, function, nested, arguments, yield

The code below uses the context manager to ensure that the code 'set something up' and 'shut things down' is always executed. What I can't understand what role the yield keyword plays here and how the bar argument is declared.

```py
@contextmanager
def function(foo):
    # set something up

    def nestedfunction(bar):
        # do something with bar
        pass

    try:
        yield nestedfunction
    finally:
        # shut things down
```

The function will be called as follows

```py
reporter = function(foo)
```

Comment: So you know what yield is and how to use?

Comment: @Wonka I think I understand the use of the yield keyword in the context of a for loop returning a generator. I do not however understand the use of it here, where it returns a function object.

Comment: So probably you are using yield when you can just use a return?

Comment: I think I have solved my problem by being exposed to the idea of closures, this explained why no arguments have been passed https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-closures/

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)?

Answer (score 0):

> The function will be called as follows
>
> ```
> reporter = function(foo)
> ```

This isn't true. It's a context manager, so would be used as:

```py
with function(foo="foo") as reporter:
    reporter(bar="bar1")
    reporter(bar="bar2")
```